# Undo and Redo in Visual studio community edition 2022 Not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Undo and Redo not working, sucks! (visual studio community edition 2022)

I've been developing using VS on and off for 15 years, never been a problem in the past.
Today I got a project that needs me to dev some C#. Installed the latest ver of VS (visual studio community edition 2022) looks good loads fine woohoo!

Oops I need to undo the last 3 characters I typed (such as typing "WTF") I'll just tap Ctrl+z 3 times and be fine... NOPE! not working and the toolbar icon shows as if it's not available.

Does anyone have an idea of how to tune on or fix this basic feature?

Thanks
Shane

Comment: I have the same issue.  If you report it to Microsoft (Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a Problem), and give us the link to the post, I'm sure we can all upvote there.

Comment: As suggested by Pierre I reported it, see:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Undo-not-working-in-Visual-studio-2022/10291503?ref=native&refTime=1677429564225&refUserId=b0ca2e16-fe3e-4870-b98a-5bbc1b4bd0f6
Btw none of the solutions posted here worked for me...

Comment: It is the same issue as https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C--Edit-REDOUNDO-stop-working-after-/10267793

Comment: Restarting my computer fixed it for me.

Answer (score 15):

This problem seems to be closely related to **Hot Reload** feature in visual studio 2022.

To solve this problem temporary, disable hot reloading in visual studio, and edit and continue option in debug.

You can also disabled hot reloading feature while keeping watch running from command-line by using this command with switch:

`dotnet watch run --no-hot-reload`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio has to be restarted after changing these settings.

Comment: My option was already disabled, but I'm still experiencing the problem. Undo randomly stops working, requiring IDE restart.

Comment: As of version 17.7.6, this fix works for me.

Comment: Was also having this issue in version 17.9 and this worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Fix worked for me.[Link](https://timgolisch.wordpress.com/2019/11/06/fix-visual-studio-freeze-for-tfs/?unapproved=3255&moderation-hash=80b05516f6c802369ee2c063db9cfd82#comment-3255)

1. Close Visual Studio
2. If you have any pending changes for TFS, grab a copy of all of your
   changes before you do anything else.  I use poor-man’s backup (zip)
   to capture any/all possible changes, and move the zip(s) to
   somewhere safe. Again, don’t take a chance on losing your changes!
3. Wipe your TFS cache: Find
   C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation##\Cache
   (where [Username] is your Windows login). The cache is that folder
   and everything inside of it.  I just renamed my Cache folder to
   Cache.bak.  Just in case.  I thought about just putting it in the
   recycle bin, so I could maybe undo if I needed it, but I figured I
   might need to fish-out an old file or two from the old cache folder,
   and it is easy to delete it later, when I confirmed that I was
   good-to-go.
4. Reopen Visual Studio.  It will automatically rebuild a new cache
   folder for you, which is not corrupted.
5. Bingo!  The darn thing starts working and I stop using foul
   language.

Comment: This solution seems to have worked for me, while the other one didn't. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't have a cache folder in mine. I archived the entire foundation directory, but Visual Studio did not regenerate another one on startup.

Comment: On my recent arch-linux installation with vscode 1.74.2 I had to clear the ~/.config/Code/Cache directory to make undo work again.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest fix for me:

When undo doesn't work, just Ctrl-Tab to a different file then Ctrl-Tab back!

Undo works again, even for what you just wanted to undo.