# Redo button or shortcut does not work in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When I try to CTRL + Y or to click on any of the redo buttons they do nothing. Just for more info I have Resharper + NCrunch, do not know if Resharper could make the problem somehow.

Thanks for your help.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733181/5393734) but does not work.

Comment: Have you tried disabling Resharper and/or NCrunch? I use Resharper with VS2022 and have no issues with undo and redo. What source files are you having problems with? Do you have any other extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's GitHub Copilot.

See [#14027](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/14027) on GitHub's Discussions: VS2022 - Redo doesn't work when the Copilot extension is enabled.

You'll have to disable the extension to fix it.

When Visual Studio is acting up, first run `devenv.exe /safemode` to start it without any extensions. If it works, restart and disable the most recently installed extension.

Comment: You are right, the problem is with Copilot, did not even thought on it when thinking on problems.
Thanks for your help!